# how to invoke super keyword with argument in the child class in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I have the following code. In the sublcass `C`, I have commented out a line that works fine. I want to know how to use `super` keyword that takes parameters. The one I have below does not work, which is also commented out. Any suggestions here. Thanks

```
class A:
 def __init__(self, val):
        self.a = val


class B(A):
  pass

class C(A):
  def __init__(self, val):
        #A.__init__(self, val)
        #super(C,self,val).__init__() -- This does not work;
        self.a += val

print A(4).a
print B(5).a
print C(6).a
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second one, you need to pass `val` to the function `__init__()`.

Notice in the working one you call `A.__init__(self, val)`

Whereas in the nonworking on you put all this in the `super()` call: `super(C,self,val).__init__()`
The reason this doesn't is that the function `A.__init__()` requires **2** parameters, the object itself and a parameter `val`. But you've only given it `self`, from the `super()` method. The parameter `val` in super does nothing as super only takes 2 arguments itself.

If you change this to `super(C,self).__init__(val)` it should work.

Comment: thanks, is `A.__init__(self, val)` is better than using `super(C,self).__init__(val)`

Comment: I'd err on the side of `super()` as it means you don't need to keep track of what exactly you are calling and if the inheritance changes you'll still call the right method.